# Нет перехода на страницу записи

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Вот так объявляю кастомный тип записи

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');
function my_custom_init(){
    register_post_type('flats', array(
        'labels'             => array(
            'name'               => 'Недвижимость',
            'singular_name'      => 'Недвижимость',
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить новую недвижимость',
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавить новую недвижимость',
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактировать недвижимость',
            'new_item'           => 'Новая недвижимость',
            'view_item'          => 'Посмотреть недвижимость',
            'search_items'       => 'Найти недвижимость',
            'not_found'          => 'Ничего не найдено',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'В корзине нет недвижимости',
            'parent_item_colon'  => '',
            'menu_name'          => 'Недвижимость'

          ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => true,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array('title','excerpt')
    ) );
}
```

Вывод записей работает

```
<?php
    global $post;

    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'flats',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
    ];

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    query_posts($args);
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
    ?>
    <div>
        <a href="<? the_permalink();?>"><? the_title();?></a>
    </div>
    <img src="<? echo get_field('object_card_image')['url'];?>" alt="<? echo get_field('object_card_image')['alt'];?>" />
    <br />
<?
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

В файле single-flats.php указывается шаблон записи и тип постов

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Объект недвижимости
Template Post Type: flats
*/
?>
```

Но при клике на `<a href="<? the_permalink();?>"><? the_title();?></a>` идет переход на 404 страницу. А нужен переход на страницу записи. Где тут ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После всех этих процедур нужно перейти на Настройки -> Постоянные ссылки -> Сохранить изменения.

Comment: это ответ или дополнение вопроса? если второе, то удалите его, пожалуйста, и дополните сам вопрос.